# SetState hook does not render the data after a timeout

Tags: reactjs

My data is not shown when the app launches. It only shows when I tried to inspect the page.

I am reading JSON data that make take some time to be available. So, I added a async/await.

How do I fix my code so it displays on load?

Here is a snippet of my code:

```js
const WeatherWidget = ({ id, editMode }) => {
    const [roles, setRoles] = useState();
 
    const getGoalData = async () => {
        return (
            [
                {
                    "username": "user1",
                    "goal": "$5,000,200"

                },
                {
                    "username": "user2",
                    "goal": "$5,000,200"

                },
                {
                    "username": "user3",
                    "goal": "$4,000,199"

                },

            ]
        );

    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const setDataRole = async () => {
            var json = await getGoalData();
           
            setRoles(json)
        }
        setDataRole();

    }, [])
    return (
        <Container>
            <div>
                ticker from widget config
            </div>
            <StyledUl>
                <Ticker>
                    {({ index }) => (
                        <>
                            {roles && roles.map(({ username, goal }, i) => (
                                <>
                                    {i === 0 ? null : ','}
                                    <StyledSpanName>
                                        <span className="name">{username}</span>
                                    </StyledSpanName>
                                    <StyledSpanGoal> <span className="goal">{goal}</span></StyledSpanGoal>
                                </>
                            ))
                            }
                        </>
                    )}
                </Ticker>
            </StyledUl>
        </Container>
    );
};
```

Comment: UseEffect is for side effects, changing the state isn't a side effect

Comment: Don't use timeouts, use promises, and not promises that wrap timeouts. `getGoalData`, as written, is instantaneous, and doesn't do anything with JSON (which is a text format). If it actually fetches data from an API, then that should create a promise or an observable that you can wait for and make the call of `setRoles` contingent upon.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to load anything. The data is right there in the code. Just put it in `roles` right from the start.

In fact, you don't even need to use `useState`, since you never mutate the `roles` state. It could (and probably should) be a constant.

```
const WeatherWidget = ({ id, editMode }) => {
    const [roles, setRoles] = useState(
        [
            {
                "username": "user1",
                "goal": "$5,000,200"

            },
            {
                "username": "user2",
                "goal": "$5,000,200"

            },
            {
                "username": "user3",
                "goal": "$4,000,199"

            },

        ]
    );

    return (
        <Container>
            <div>
                ticker from widget config
            </div>
            <StyledUl>
                <Ticker>
                    {({ index }) => (
                        <>
                            {roles && roles.map(({ username, goal }, i) => (
                                <>
                                    {i === 0 ? null : ','}
                                    <StyledSpanName>
                                        <span className="name">{username}</span>
                                    </StyledSpanName>
                                    <StyledSpanGoal> <span className="goal">{goal}</span></StyledSpanGoal>
                                </>
                            ))
                            }
                        </>
                    )}
                </Ticker>
            </StyledUl>
        </Container>
    );
};
```

Comment: Thanks.. I am hardcoding the data now. I will read it from a different source..I want to simulate the delay.. So, I added the async/await to my code. but it only show when I view page source

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you forgot `async`:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        const setDataRole = async () => { // here
            var res = await getGoalData()
            var data = await res.json()
           
            setRoles(data)
        }
        setDataRole();

    }, [])
```

Comment: Thanks, I added but same issue. It works  if I just right click on the page and view source and then close . It seem to be a timing issue but I don't see how to fix it

Comment: Can you show us the actual getGoalData function, because i dont see anything wrong with your current code

Comment: And do you have a good reason for not coverting json data to javascript object? Try the code I updated

Comment: Thanks.. The getGoalData is getting the value from env variable . Not sure why it not working to start but only when I right click and view source. Is it possible to run the code